# Retrieving string from an array within a json object

Tags: android, json

I'll keep it short. I want to obtain the string value from "token". But from what I can see there is a "data" array within my json object. How do I retrieve the array and, specifically, the token string from this array?

```
{
"response":true,
    "state":8,"data":{
        "token":"$2a$08$oeH79FjMV6ZQTO.9qqfToujNBbst420Xx7o9jJdFgbJsJijtEpX\/O",
        "numbers":[{
            "number":"4581102282",
            "enabled":"0",
            "custid":"1528511113",
            "route":"rock",
            "clir":"2",
            "mob":"1",
            "clip":"",
            "mbx":"0",
            "trunk":"2",
            "valid_from":"2011-09-07",
            "valid_to":"2011-10-05"
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: just to clarify - the "data" tag does not refer to an array, it is already an object within the main JSON object.

Comment: I don't have time to write a proper answer now, but I'd like to draw your attention to GSON - google's JSON parser. It is great for Android and really simple to use. Hopefully someone can pick up on this comment and make an answer out of it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use

```
JSONObject jsonObj=new JSONObject(response);
JSONObject jsonData=jsonObj.getJSONObject("data");
String token=jsonData.getString("token");
```